# how i can make my vue 2 components to use in my rewrite to vue 3?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vuejs3

i have a plan to use my vue 2 components in my new project vue 3, is that possible?, let say i have vue 3 project, in my vue 2 components i have **FAQ** and **About Us** components, then i create routes in my Vue 3 to use that vue 2 components, is that possible ??

i have tried use migration build, but it was a lot of error that i cant resolved, so i decided to rewrite them :( , what things i need to do to make this possible guys,

example in vue 2

```
/src/components/faq
/src/components/about-us
```

in vue 3

```
// in route.js
import {FAQ, AboutUS} from "my-component-vue2";

export default Routes [{
  path: "/faq",
  component: () => FAQ
}]
```

Answer (score 0):

You could possibly share the components using some setup with webpack federated modules, i.e. run microfrontends with your Vue2 components in one and your Vue3 in another with a container to manage/route? There's nothing stopping you just copying all the components from the Vue2 project into the Vue3 project and seeing if they are all working before you start making new Vue3 components. Or have you tried that already?

[Webpack Module Federation](https://webpack.js.org/concepts/module-federation/)

Here's a link to things that may break [Breaking Changes in Vue3](https://v3-migration.vuejs.org/breaking-changes/introduction.html#breaking-changes)